# Entity Framework multiple join types with dates, group by and count

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a chat system that consist of 3 tables: Users, RoomJoins (private conversation room that you have joined) and Chats (list of chat messages with a timestamp).

I want to get a list of all private rooms for a given user, followed by the number of new chat messages he has received since his last login.

The sql query that works (maybe can be improved, but certainly works) is:

```
select a.roomid, b.userid, m.firstpicurl, count(p.roomid) as cuenta from roomjoin a
 inner join roomjoin b
on b.roomid=a.roomid and a.userid<>b.userid
inner join myuser m on m.id=b.userid
 left join
 chat p on p.roomid=a.roomid and p.sentwhen > a.lastseen
 where a.userid=45 and a.active=1
  group by a.roomid, b.userid, m.firstpicurl
```

that basically says: give me all roomids (private conversations) for userid=45, also the userid of the person that sent me the message, his picture and the number of chat messages where sentwhen > user.lastseen

the result will be something like

```
roomid  userid  firstpicurl  cuenta
1        43     http://...     3
2        37     http://...     0
```

meaning the userid 43 has sent you 3 messages since your last login, while the user 37 didn't sent you anything new

Now, I try to translate this into EF and I kind of got it working, but the problem is that I can't find a way to query using the sentwhen > lastseen date format because it doesn't allow for that. And if I try with Where clauses, I never get the correct answer. Here is my existing try (without sentwhen > lastseen)

```
from a in db.RoomJoins.Where(c => c.userid == u.id && c.active == true).OrderBy(c => c.roomid)
                                 from b in db.RoomJoins.Where(fp => fp.roomid == a.roomid && fp.userid != a.userid)
                                 from m in db.Users.Where(m => b.userid == m.id)
                                 join p in db.Chats on a.roomid equals p.roomid into j1
                                 from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 group j2 by new { a.roomid, b.userid, m.firstpicurl } into g
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     roomid = g.Key.roomid,
                                     userid = g.Key.userid,
                                     firstpicurl = g.Key.firstpicurl,
                                     count = g.Count()
                                 };
```

so my code seems to work but it has 2 problems:
1) it doesn't take into account the timestamp, I just want a count of messages after my lastseen
2) I get a count of 1 when it should be 0. So I would get something like this

```
roomid  userid  firstpicurl  cuenta
1        43     http://...     3
2        37     http://...     1  <-- this should be 0
```

anyone knows how to achieve what i'm looking for?

**First answer:**
This one seems to work but it looks very complex. Is there a way to make simpler?

```
from a in db.RoomJoins.Where(c => c.userid == 45 && c.active == true)
                                 from b in db.RoomJoins.Where(fp => fp.roomid == a.roomid && fp.userid != a.userid)
                                 from m in db.Users.Where(m => b.userid == m.id)
                                 from p in db.Chats.Where(p => p.roomid==a.roomid && 
                                            p.sentwhen > a.lastseen).DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     roomid = a.roomid,
                                     userid = b.userid,
                                     firstpicurl = m.firstpicurl,
                                     cid = p.Id                                    
                                 } into j1
                                 group j1 by new { j1.roomid, j1.userid, j1.firstpicurl } into g
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     roomid = g.Key.roomid,
                                     userid = g.Key.userid,
                                     firstpicurl = g.Key.firstpicurl,
                                     count = g.Count(e => e.cid!=null)
                                 };
```

Comment: What happens when you add an additional join on constraint to the join statement of table p? Much like you did in your sql query?

Comment: regardless of performance, `Where` clause should always work after all. It it does not work, that means your LINQ query is wrong at some other point.

Comment: General advise that I can give is do not spend your time on translating SQL queries to EF. This is simply counter productive with no added benefit. I've learnt it the hard way on a project where I could not even control the database schema, and every query took 3 times as much to write: once in sql that was familiar, second in EF and the third is figuring out why it still does not work. EF is brilliant with simple schemas and also very good for change tracking. For the rest call a SP.

Comment: The SQL query `count(p.roomid)` will count all ***non-null*** values. But the `g.Count()` will count all (including null values). So in this case you just need to modify it to count just non null value (null values are added due to `DefaultIfEmpty()`), it should be like this `count = g.Count(e => e != null)`. That should work (regard of you using the `Where` clause on `Chats`).

Comment: thanks for the Count hint. That fixes the 1 instead of 0, still no clue how to include in that query the lastseen. I can't seem to mix the group by, left join and where clause

Comment: it seems this code works, but it seems very complicated... two selects to get the same result than the original sql statement. I add it to the end of the original question

Comment: The query is complicated because of your design (it maybe standard or not). As you see, the final result involves `roomid` (from roomjoin), `userid` and `firstpicurl` (from myuser), `count` (from chat). So all those tables are involved, you need group by, projection, ... it looks like unable to be simpler, unless you re-design your tables. Of course I don't understand much about the semantics (from which the query should be built) as well as the relationships between your tables. My advice is stick with what you have now. I don't think someone here could help improve it more.

Comment: yep, but reading around the web it seems there is a way to do the group by only on the chat table field without the need to place roomid,userid and firstpicurl into it. I just can't figure out yet how. Is there a way to know what's the generated sql of the EF statement? I'm using visual studio

Comment: btw @Hopeless place your comment as an answer, nobody answered it completely but at least your answer helped me figure out the count 0 issue so you deserve some credit.

Comment: well I'm glad it helped you but answer now is not really needed. You can set the `DbContext.Database.Log` to some `Action<string>` to log out the sql query, such as `DbContext.Database.Log = (s) => System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(s);`

Answer (score 0):

```
join p in db.Chats.Where(x  => x.sentwhen > a.lastseen) 
              on a.roomid equals p.roomid into j1
```

Comment: you can't do a join/where/on

Comment: @JoaquinGrech Did you try?

Comment: obviously, that was the first thing I did, a copy and paste... immediate error, it doesn't understand you place "on" after a Where method. You can try it yourself.

Comment: Same here. What message did you get?

Comment: it says "a" does not exist in the current context (inside the where clause). So it can't see the "a" from the previous select

Comment: @JoaquinGrech That's not saying you cannot do an on in conjunction with a where. That's saying it doesn't know what "a" is in the context.

Comment: you are right. But still it won't work, since it can't find the info to get a working condition. Unless there is a way to pass it into the where clause somehow

Comment: @JoaquinGrech hmm Its funny because you have joined tables referencing other tables in a similar way. Could you try moving the "p" join up to be the first table referenced after "a"?

Comment: same error. I really don't understand why it won't pick it up there but it seems the "join" makes it begin with a clean context :?